# How to set the advanced SSL options in getmail?

Tags: getmail

I just setup `getmail` with SSL. I ran the verification as suggested in [the documentation](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/configuration.html#retriever-ssl-extra):

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect HOST:PORT < /dev/null 2>/dev/null \
  | grep '^[[:space:]]*i:' | tail -n 1
issuer=/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=Gandi/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
```

The documentation says "If the server's certificate cannot be validated based upon the supplied trusted root certificates, getmail will abort the connection." So I assume that `getmail` was able to verify the server's certificate. I also successfully ran a `SimplePOP3SSLRetriever` with no optional parameters.

But the default location `/System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/` on macOS has no files and the Keychain has no certificates installed. So I don't know which filepath to give to the optional parameter `ca_certs` to force verification of the server's SSL certificate.

My questions are:

- how can I verify that `SimplePOP3SSLRetriever` runs on an encrypted connection?
- where can I find a root certificate to verify the server's certificate, or how can I download a root certificate without risking of a man-in-the-middle attack?
- how to set the `ssl_fingerprints` variable to verify that the server's certificate has not changed?